# Unable to upload files over 500MB while upload_max_filesize is set to 1G

Tags: php, nginx, file-upload, large-files

I realise there are a ton of questions on this already but i've followed all of them and can't find any information on how to further debug this not working.

I can upload a file of 490 MB absolutely fine. I cannot upload a file of 562.8 MB.

I'm running php 7.0.11 with fpm, nginx 1.11.3, ubuntu 16 and using Laravel 5.1

My php ini settings are:

> upload_max_filesize 1GB
>
> post_max_size 1GB
>
> memory_limit 1GB (this shouldn't actually be needed but i've tried it anyway)

My nginx settings:

> client_max_body_size 1G

I haven't found any reference to any other variables that need to be changed or that may interfere.

When I upload `$_FILES` looks like:

```
["file"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=> string(36) "CSBgGvDIAaZtbC4lmliLevHf0bAnWiKM.rar"
    ["type"]=> string(0) ""
    ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) ""
    ["error"]=> int(1)
    ["size"]=> int(0)
  }
```

There is nothing in my nginx or php error logs.

`$_SERVER['content_length']` is 652844444 which is the correct length of the file.

The `'error'` is listed as 1. I don't know if this is 1 as in true, or 1 as in the relevant error message. The php docs list the error message for 1 in the docs as:

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

But both of:

```
echo phpinfo();
echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
```

Show 1GB so the file shouldn't exceed it, because it's 562.8 MB.

With no further error messages and having followed every instruction and guide I can find on Google i'm at a complete loss as to what it could be.

I am also using Cloudflare but it is turned off for this sub domain and the limits on Cloudflare are 100MB not 500MB so I don't think it's anything to do with that.

Is there any way to further debug this? I'm at a complete loss at this point.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php according to this something in your PHP INI configuration didn't stick. If you're using PHP-FPM then you may need to make sure you're changing the correct configurations. It's a but odd when it comes to what it reads.

Comment: That's what I quoted? Can you explain what you mean? If i'm doing `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')` on the same page as the form, surely those are the php.ini settings that are being used.

Comment: Maybe this is something with timeout? You test the upload on localhost, or on the external server? You can try this one: https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/increase-script-execution-time/

Comment: I guess the question is more like, is the `ini_get` ran in the same script where the upload is handled?

Comment: If it timed out I wouldn't get to the php file and be able to `var_dump($_FILES)` would I? From what I can tell there is no timeout for files that would still process the php

Comment: Yes it's the same script. It's Laravel everything runs through the same index.php file on the same domain. Ive also just checked ini_get() along with the var_dump($_FILES) and it still says 1GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved this. Really really annoyingly. The problem was that I typed 1GB instead of 1G in php.ini. No error messages were given and it wasn't clear at all that it wasn't using 1 Gigabyte. But php.ini won't recognise things like 1KB, 1MB or 1GB you have to use without the B.

Lesson learned, alot of time wasted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a cloud/hosted server?  Many hosted servers have hard limits on max file uploads that they don't let you override even with an ini file.  If you are using a hosted server, you may need to contact your hosting provider to override the limit for you.

Comment: It's a digitalocean droplet with Ubuntu 16. I do not believe there are any such limits. A Google didn't bring anything up

Answer (score 0):

if you are using **wp site** plugin
consider change both Constants in php.in(after wp-config.php update not worked  .so many developer suggest in stackOverflow) after do like this worked .ubuntu 20

**Location**

sudo nano /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini

**Constant**

```
post_max_size = 1G

upload_max_filesize = 1G
```